# Bootstrap 5 Tabs are not Working In Wordpress with ACF

Tags: html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, bootstrap-5, custom-post-type

I have made tabs using bootstrap 5 now when i converted into wordpress code to make it dynamic the tabs are stopped working the html code is proper also the php code proper then also not working

Here is my code which i have used

https://codeshare.io/oQM9Lb

Comment: What do you mean by “not working”? Could you explain what behavior you’re trying to achieve, and what problems you’re having with the tabs?

Comment: tab is not working see screenshot -https://prnt.sc/FR2Xx04QBB38

Comment: When you say the tabs “aren’t working”, do you mean that when you click on one it doesn’t change to that tab?

Comment: yes its  doesn't change

Comment: Copy the rendered HTML from the page source and create a runnable code snippet with that HTML and the required JS files in question so that I could be tested.

Comment: It is wordpress website so i alrady share the code above

Comment: https://codepen.io/mayur-galaiya/pen/gOzqyQb here is output of code

Comment: My error has been solved data-bs-toggle="pill" was missing